# Manage the wrappers in Snakemake

Tags: wrapper, snakemake

I am trying to make a Snakemake pipeline using a configuration file config.yaml.

```
--- 
samples:
- Sample_1: reads/raw_reads_1
- Sample_2: reads/raw_reads_2
- Sample_3: reads/raw_reads_3
 
reference:
- "path/to/reference.fasta" 
...
```

Following the good practices given in the Snakemake wrapper repository, I have used wrappers commands as much as possible.
https://snakemake-wrappers.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
However I have observed that the input/outputs of the different wrappers do not match.
Is there a way to manage the names of the files between the rules to connect the wrappers without modifying them?

```
import os
import snakemake.io
import glob

configfile: "config.yaml"

rule all:
        input:
                expand("mapped/{sample}.bam", sample=config["samples"])

rule fastqc:
        input:
                "reads/{sample}.fastq"
        output:
                html="qc/fastqc/{sample}.html",
                zip="qc/fastqc/{sample}_fastqc.zip" # the suffix _fastqc.zip is necessary for multiqc to find the file. If not using multiqc, you are free to choose an arbitrary filename
        params:
                extra = "--quiet"
        log:
                "logs/fastqc/{sample}.log"
        threads: 1
        resources:
                mem_mb = 1024
        wrapper:
                "v2.6.0/bio/fastqc"

rule bwa_index:
        input:
                "{genome}.fasta", 
        output:
                idx=multiext("{genome}", ".amb", ".ann", ".bwt", ".pac", ".sa"),
        log:
                "logs/bwa_index/{genome}.log",
        params:
                algorithm="bwtsw",
        wrapper:
                "v2.6.0/bio/bwa/index"

rule bwa_mem:
        input:
                reads=["reads/{sample}.1.fastq", "reads/{sample}.2.fastq"],
                idx=multiext("genome", ".amb", ".ann", ".bwt", ".pac", ".sa"),
        output:
                "mapped/{sample}.bam",
        log:
                "logs/bwa_mem/{sample}.log",
        params:
                extra=r"-R '@RG\tID:{sample}\tSM:{sample}'",
                sorting="none",  # Can be 'none', 'samtools' or 'picard'.
                sort_order="queryname",  # Can be 'queryname' or 'coordinate'.
                sort_extra="",  # Extra args for samtools/picard.
                threads: 8
        wrapper:
                "v2.6.0/bio/bwa/mem"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrappers' purpose is only to wrap the logic how to do something. There is no magic way to automatically connect inputs to outputs for rules. It is your job to define input and output values for your purposes. Values in wrappers do not match, as they are set just for testing purposes.

That's the whole answer, however I will try to provide some example, but your config for samples is incorrect.

```
def get_sample_names():
    # return list of sample names

rule all:
    input:
        bamqc=expand("mapped/{sample}.bam", sample=get_sample_names()),
        fastqc=expand("qc/fastqc/{sample}_{pair}.html", sample=get_sample_names(), pair=["1","2"]),

rule bwa_index:
    input:
        "{prefix_reference}.fasta", 
    output:
        idx=multiext("{prefix_reference}", ".amb", ".ann", ".bwt", ".pac", ".sa"),
    log:
        "{prefix_reference}/logs/bwa_index.log",
    params:
        algorithm="bwtsw",
    wrapper:
        "v2.6.0/bio/bwa/index"


rule bwa_mem:
    input:
        reads=[
            "reads/{sample}.1.fastq.gz",
            "reads/{sample}.2.fastq.gz",
        ],
        idx=multiext(
            os.path.splitext(config["reference"]),
            ".amb",
            ".ann",
            ".bwt",
            ".pac",
            ".sa",
        ),
    output:
        "mapped/{sample}.bam",
    ...


rule fastqc:
    input:
        "reads/{sample}.{pair}.fastq"
    output:
        html="qc/fastqc/{sample}_{pair}.html",
        zip="qc/fastqc/{sample}_{pair}_fastqc.zip"
    params:
        extra = "--quiet"
    log:
        "logs/fastqc/{sample}_{pair}.log"
    wrapper:
        "v2.6.0/bio/fastqc"
```

In the example I presumed that all your data is in `reads/`. Sample names can be either provided by the config or you can glob for all samples in `reads` directory. The other, more complex and advanced way to manage your input reads is to use [pepfiles](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/configuration.html#configuring-scientific-experiments-via-peps).
I would advise further to check existing workflows, for example by checking newest workflows from the [catalog](https://snakemake.github.io/snakemake-workflow-catalog/)

Comment: Thank you @skanderbeg. I thought indeed that all wrappers shared the same variables, but it was due to my unfamiliarity with snakemake.
I guess I was trying to set up a pipeline from scratch to understand how snakemake work. But it is indeed more sound to use and fork existing workflow. 
Using pepfile could be a good solution for a problem I had which was to input a specimen ID to my raw reads file which name is unrelated. I guess it would be possible with pepfiles. Thanks again.